# Extract Unique list & find Maximum

Tags: excel, vba

This code is trying to create unique name list with their Maximum values but has some bug with `if Not Exists`.  Can you help me solve the problem?

```
Sub UniqeMAX() 

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Dn As Range

Set Rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

For Each Dn In Rng

If Not.Exists(Dn.Value) Then

.Add Dn.Value, Dn(, 3)
 Else
 .Item(Dn.Value) = Application.max(.Item(Dn.Value), Dn(, 3))

End If
Next

Range("D1").Resize(.Count, 3) = Application.Transpose(Array(.Keys, .Items))

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use the code formatting tools

Comment: @Mathew,, mostly I'm using, my Cell phone,, so that some formatting related problems arises,, nw bttr chk the bug and suggest corrections. ☺

Comment: The only thing I can see that doesn't work is that `Range("D1").Resize(.Count, 3)` should be `Range("D1").Resize(.Count, 2)` (otherwise it writes out an extra column of `#N/A` values).  What do you mean by `"has some bug"`?

Comment: `If Not.Exists(Dn.Value) Then` should be `If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then`

Comment: does `If Not.Exists(Dn.Value) Then` really work for you? The syntax is `object.Exists(key)` and `Not` is not an object...

Comment: @TimWilliams bam... I was to slow :(

Comment: 4 seconds in it - I'd call that a tie...

Comment: @DirkReichel `If Not.Exists(Dn.Value) Then` gets automatically converted by the VBE to `If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then` - it knows that `Not` is a keyword.

Comment: @ThomasInzina `Application.max(.Item(Dn.Value), Dn(, 3))` is taking the maximum of the current value in the dictionary for key `Dn.Value` (set when `Not .Exists(Dn.Value)` is `True`) and the value of the cell **2** columns to the right.

Comment: @ThomasInzina and the `Application.Transpose` worked for me - although it only created two columns (naturally) and therefore the `Resize` to 3 columns generated a lot of `#N/A` values for the 3rd column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151124/discussion-between-yowe3k-and-thomas-inzina).

Comment: So it appears that the `Application.Transpose` will give a type mismatch error if any of the keys in column A only appear once, and the corresponding value in column C is empty.  Providing data (hopefully numeric data so that the `Max` doesn't crash) exists in column C for every entry in column A, the `Application.Transpose` should work.

Comment: Thanks guys for responding the issue,, at my end error is, If not. Exists(DN.Value)Then and it's Bug I think. 
Let me try Range("D1"). Resize (. Count, 2)

Comment: @Dirk,, DN, dictionary has been already declared as an Object earlier,, ☺